# Regex expression for selecting a folder and its subfolders

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've been trying to get the right regex expression for selecting a folder and its subfolders for several days.

This is to avoid generating an Identity folder into a Sitemap.
The project is in .Net Core 2.2 Razor Page.

According to online testers, my Regex is fine, but it doesn't work in practice.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultUI().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
            // If the LoginPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults 
            // the path to /Account/Login.
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            // If the AccessDeniedPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults 
            // the path to /Account/AccessDenied.
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<VolkaDbContext>();
        services.AddTransient<IBlogRepository, BlogRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IPortfolioRepository, PortfolioRepository>();


        services.AddRouting(options =>
        {
            options.LowercaseUrls = true;
        });
        services.AddRazorPagesSitemap(options=> {
            options.IgnoreExpression = @".*\/Identity\/(?!example).*";
        });

        services.AddDirectoryBrowser();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```

I use the SodaPop.RazorPagesSitemap library to generate a sitemap.

The Regex expression with the result I need is here:
[Regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*%5C%2FIdentity%5C%2F%28%3F!example%29.*&i=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44313%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FManage%2FDeletePersonalData%0D%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44313%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FManage%2FEnableAuthenticator%0D%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44313%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FManage%2FIndex%0D%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44313%2FIndex)

Will there be someone to advise me?

Well thank you

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Please [edit] your question to include the regex you have in your question itself, not on an external site. Also include the input you have for the regex and what you want to match/check with it. Also show the actual source code you have as a [mcve] and explain what the problem with this code is.

Comment: You talk about folders and sub-folders yet pasted some totally unrelated code and no regex, and no input data. Hows about, paste a list of test data, and your expected results, and the regexs you have tried

Comment: Are you using [this library](https://github.com/ctolkien/SodaPop.RazorPagesSitemap)?